# Telegram web login widget: obtain chat_id

Tags: authentication, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm trying to add a user authorization to my page using Telegram's Login Widget. The widget  works as expected but there are a lack of information about how to use it in real scenarios.

1. When the authentication succeedes my bot is allowed to send messages to the user (data-request-access="write") but I am not clear how my bot can to obtain a correspondent **chat_id** to do that. The bot does not receive any event about user's login.
2. Is there any possibility to check programmatically user's session status automatically? The widget must have any callback that indicates that the session is already created. Otherwise every time user refreshes the page he must click the button to init page's authorization process.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

1. The chat_id is the same as the id sent to your app when a user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

After the user has authorized.yu, you need to check his data and make sure that it is real. This can be done using the [TgWebValid library](https://github.com/CrazyTapok-bit/tgWebValid). After that, you can log in as on any other site, since you have the user data. You can write them to the database, you can do jwt, cookie or other type of authorization